# Joining tables (Oracle) without join columns

Tags: sql, oracle

Okay so Im pretty new to ORACLE here is my question

> DISPLAY STUDENTS INFORMATION ( STUDENTID, LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME,
>   COURSEID, COURSENAME AND MARKS.
>
> The results of this query must be sorted by coursename.

Table STUDENTS:

```
1111111111  Smith   Carolyn 124 Rolling Hills St    Fullerton
2222222222  Maradona    Diego   100 Imperial St Brea
3333333333  Messi   Lionel  225 Bristol St  Irvine
4444444444  Crosby  Sidney  869 Coriander St    Brea
5555555555  Ali Mohammed    125 Third Street    Fullerton
```

Table COURSES:

```
J01 Java    4
B01 DataBase    4
```

Table RESULTS:

```
1111111111  B01 110 18
2222222222  B01 110 20
3333333333  B01 110 18
4444444444  B01 909 14
5555555555  B01 909 18
1111111111  J01 110 18
2222222222  J01 110 19
3333333333  J01 909 12
4444444444  J01 110 11
5555555555  J01 110 18
1111111111  B01 110 18
2222222222  B01 110 20
3333333333  B01 110 18
4444444444  B01 909 14
5555555555  B01 909 18
1111111111  J01 110 18
2222222222  J01 110 19
3333333333  J01 909 12
4444444444  J01 110 11
5555555555  J01 110 18
1111111111  B01 110 18
2222222222  B01 110 20
3333333333  B01 110 18
4444444444  B01 909 14
5555555555  B01 909 18
1111111111  J01 110 18
2222222222  J01 110 19
3333333333  J01 909 12
4444444444  J01 110 11
5555555555  J01 110 18
```

This problem is really bothering me I cant figure it out.....
if someone can help me I would really appreciate it!

Thanks everyone!

Comment: What are the column names? What is the expected result?

Comment: Was there a question?  We see the example rows from three tables, ostensibly named `STUDENTS`, `COURSES`, and `RESULTS`. What is the problem? What is there to figure out?  If you want rows returned in a specific order, add an `ORDER BY` clause to a `SELECT` statement.

Comment: I don't understand even the title. What do you mean by "without join columns"? And ALL CAPS are generally considered rude; I will edit your title so you are not shouting at us.

Comment: sorry man lol I just copy and pasted it

Answer (score 2):

You haven't given any schema descriptions, so I assumed the column names based on what column you expect in output. This should do:

```
select
    s.studentid,
    s.lastname,
    s.firstname,
    c.courseid,
    c.coursename,
    r.marks
from students s
inner join results r
    on s.studentid = r.studentid
inner join courses c
    on r.courseid = c.courseid
order by c.coursename;
```

**EDIT:**

Based on given DDLs:

```
CREATE TABLE SALESPERSON (ID NUMBER (5), NAME VARCHAR2(20), AGE VARCHAR2(20), SALARY NUMBER(8)); 
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (ID NUMBER(5), NAME VARCHAR2(20), CITY VARCHAR2(15), INDUSTRY_TYPE VARCHAR2(5));
CREATE TABLE ORDERS (NUM NUMBER(5), ORDER_DATE DATE, CUST_ID NUMBER(5), SALESPERSON_ID NUMBER(5), AMOUNT NUMBER(6));
```

You can join the tables like this:

```
select *  /* Select required columns */
from orders o
inner join customer c
on o.cust_id = c.id
inner join salesperson s
on o.salesperson_id = s.id;
```

Comment: Thanks singh, im just a little confused on what to put in the ON clause when I dont have the same column name and data type... for example SELECT s.student_id, s.last_name, c.course_id, c.course_name, r.marks
from students s inner join courses c 
on s.student_id = c.course_id
inner join results
on c.courses_id = r.marks;

Comment: Then, please specify table columns and their datatypes in the question

Comment: in the example you showed me in the on clause you are always using the same column name for each ''on s.studentid = r.studentid'' ''on r.courseid = c.courseid'' how to you join tables in you dont have any columns the same? hope that makes sense.... thank you brother

Comment: As I said,  please specify table columns and their datatypes in the question. I can't help you unless you less me

Comment: CREATE TABLE SALESPERSON 
(ID NUMBER (5),
NAME VARCHAR2(20),
AGE VARCHAR2(20),
SALARY NUMBER(8));

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER
(ID NUMBER(5),
NAME VARCHAR2(20),
CITY VARCHAR2(15),
INDUSTRY_TYPE VARCHAR2(5));


CREATE TABLE ORDERS
(NUM NUMBER(5),
ORDER_DATE DATE,
CUST_ID NUMBER(5),
SALESPERSON_ID NUMBER(5),
AMOUNT NUMBER(6));     Thank you for your help man !

Comment: @Davidito Updated my answer